# How to read data from database into powerpoint slides?

Tags: database, powerpoint

I want to know how to read data from database (ANY KIND) and present it via power point slides show? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You could, for example, create a C# application that will read the data from the database and create the powerpoint presentation using [Office Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126). How to read the data depends on what database you have.

Answer (score 1):

Why not export your data to Excel and use it from Powerpoint?

Comment: Or access the data through Excel dynamically and use it from PowerPoint